# How to properly read data from a SSLSocket and write them into a ByteBuffer

Tags: java, sockets, bytebuffer

I'm trying to get data from TCP SSL Socket and write them into a ByteBuffer ( For "seekability" purposes ).
Currently i'm doing this way:

```
private SSLSocket sock;
private ByteBuffer bf;
    this.bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufSize);
    BufferedInputStream inFromClient = new BufferedInputStream
        (this.sock.getInputStream());
        
    while (true) {
        int n = inFromClient.read();

        if (n == -1) {
            break;
        }

        bf.put((byte) n);
    }
```

But apparently the data is not written correctly and store only NUL byte.
If i try to read each byte directly from BufferedInputStream, i can see the data without issues:

```
System.out.println((char) n);
```

Instead the ByteBuffer is full of NUL bytes..

What i'm doing wrong in this case?
And also is this the correct modus operandi for reading from Socket to ByteBuffer?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: How are you checking what's in the buffer? Did you move it's position back to 0 before reading?

Comment: To know if it is correct, why are you reading into a ByteBuffer at all? I personally wouldn't do it 1 byte at a time from the stream to the ByteBuffer. I don't know the desired result though.

Comment: A little more information. If you are going to be reading into a ByteBuffer, why not use the channel that your Socket provides and then read directly into the buffer. [SocketChannel#read](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer))

Comment: @matt: SSLSockets do not have associated Channels. However one can be created easily enough from the socket inputstream with `Channels.newChannel`.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk [SSLSocket extends Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html), which has a method [getChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Socket.html#getChannel()) Although the docs on getChannel indicate sometimes they won't have a channel, maybe that is what you mean?

Comment: @matt: Correct, getChannel will always return null on a SSLSocket. You always get null for  Socket.getChannel() as well unless you first create a SocketChannel and then call the socket() method on the SocketChannel to obtain a Socket instance. But there is no similar SSLSocketChannel.

Comment: You can forget the loop and just do `this.bf = ByteBuffer.wrap(inFromClient.readAllBytes());`.

Comment: @matt i was doing 1 byte at a time for testing..
I'm trying to read it into a ByteBuffer, so i can easily go back and forth the Socket data.
That was the first idea, idk if it's the correct ones. Didn't know about channels.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Should i go with this route? Creating a Channel and obtain a Socket instance?

Comment: @VGR yeah, i read about this method, there may currently be sockets sending data endlessly, and I would like to prevent this behavior.

Comment: @matt Apparently i'm having issues converting the bytebuffer to string in this way:
`StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(this.bf).toString()`

And also didn't know that ByteBuffer get() method didn't automatically move it's position back to 0..

Using something like this did the trick:

`this.bf.get(1)`

Comment: Your current code has the same flaw:  it will read from the InputStream forever.  You can use [readNBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readNBytes(int)) instead of readAllBytes to limit how much is read.  As for ByteBuffer positioning:  the position is zero right after calling ByteBuffer.wrap, but in general, after you have filled up a ByteBuffer, you should call [flip()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#flip()) in order to read from it.

Comment: I don't want to malign the Java `ByteBuffer` but personally I have found them tricky to use and understand.  Once you "get the feel" of how to use the `.flip()` and the `.compact()` methods you may like them, but I suspect most people should just stick to raw `byte[]` arrays and not touch the `ByteBuffer` class.

Comment: @VGR Thanks. Calling flip() works like a charm :D
Yeah you're right about the code having the same flaw.. How can i implement something like a "timeout" on top of read?

Comment: *...Should I create a Channel and obtain a Socket instance...* No, you should not, because basically you don't want the Socket, you want the SSLSocket, and the class you'd want, which might logically be called SSLSocketChannel, simply does not exist.

Comment: @heph2 Timeouts will be difficult.  Why not just set a size limit instead, and use readNBytes like I suggested?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Okay fine, i'll stick with this solution..
The main idea is providing a Buffer, from a Socket, and implement a Reader on it.
This is my first attemp to Java, and OOP in general, so be kind; but the only way i found is to read bytes from Socket, put them into a ByteBuffer that extend InputStream, so that i can build a Reader (BufferedReader actually) on it

Comment: @VGR because I can't determine in advance how many bytes I'm going to read..
Actually i'm writing a client for [gemini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_(protocol)), so it's not possible for me determine how long will be a gemini page

Comment: You don’t need to know the number of bytes.  You just need to come up with a sensible maximum, to prevent reading from the stream forever.  Is a ten megabyte limit reasonable?  100 megabytes?

Comment: btw, calling flip() did the trick, so if @VGR want to submit an answer, i'll close the thread :D